# Woocommerce: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in class-wc-product-variable.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a type of variable product customized for my theme, I've managed to appear in the dropdown of product data and that can be saved without causing conflict. The problem is that seeing the product in frontend gives me the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/canopy/wp-content/plugins/Woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L83)
>   on line 83

I have traced the problem to the file [`Wordpress/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-variable-data-store-cpt.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-variable-data-store-cpt.php#L238) but the truth is that I do not know what else to do.

I leave the code that I wrote for this:

**WC_Product_variable_canopytour.php**

```
class WC_Product_Variable_CanopyTour extends WC_Product_Variable {
    public function __construct( $product ) {
        $this->product_type = 'variable_canopytour';
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }

    public function get_type() {
        return 'variable_canopytour';
    }
}
```

**class-woocommerce-custom-product.php**

```
class WCB_Woocommerce_CanopyTour_Product_Type {
    private $wcb;
    private $version;

    public function __construct( $wcb, $version ) {
        $this->wcb = $wcb;
        $this->version = $version;
    }

    public function register_canopytour_product_type() {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

        include_once(get_template_directory() . 'woocommerce/WC_Product_variable_canopytour.php');
    }

    public function add_canopytour_product( $types ) {
        $types[ 'variable_canopytour' ] = __( 'Variable Canopy Tour', $this->wcb );
        return $types;
    }

    public function get_tour_product_class($classname, $product_type) {
        if ( $product_type === "variable_canopytour" ) {
            $classname = 'WC_Product_Variable_CanopyTour';
        }
        return $classname;
    }

    public function wcb_admin_footer() {
        if ( 'product' != get_post_type() ) :
            return;
        endif;

        ?><script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
                jQuery( '.options_group.pricing' ).addClass( 'show_if_variable_canopytour show_if_simple show_if_external' ).show();
                jQuery( 'li.general_options.general_tab' ).addClass( 'show_if_variable_canopytour show_if_simple show_if_external' ).show();
                jQuery( '.variations_options.variations_tab' ).addClass( 'show_if_variable_canopytour' ).show();
                jQuery( '.enable_variation' ).addClass( 'show_if_variable_canopytour' ).show();
            });
        </script><?php
    }

    function hide_wcb_data_panel( $tabs) {
        // Other default values for 'attribute' are; general, inventory, shipping, linked_product, variations, advanced
        $tabs['shipping']['class'][] = 'hide_if_variable_canopytour';
        return $tabs;
    }
}
```

**functions.php**

```
include_once get_template_directory() . 'includes/woocommerce/class-woocommerce-custom-product.php';
$woo_ct = new WCB_Woocommerce_CanopyTour_Product_Type( "wcb", "1.0" );

add_action( 'init', array($woo_ct, 'register_canopytour_product_type') );
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', array($woo_ct, 'add_canopytour_product') );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', array($woo_ct, 'get_tour_product_class'), 10, 2 ); 
add_action( 'admin_head', array($woo_ct, 'wcb_admin_head') );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', array($woo_ct, 'hide_wcb_data_panel') );
```

I hope someone can help me understand what happens :(

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have prices for this custom product type?

Comment: Yes, I have configured them and the same error keeps coming up

Comment: Are you overriding any WooCommerce template files in your theme? Can you switch to WordPress default theme and check still getting the same error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Problem

You got that warning because the `read_price_data()` method is (as of writing) *only* available in the [`WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT.html) class and not the default one that's used for custom product type, which is [`WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT.html).

However, despite the default class doesn't have the `read_price_data()` method, calling it from the class's instance doesn't result in an exception/error because that class is instantiated through the [`WC_Data_Store`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data_Store.html) class, which has the magic method [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

```
// Case 1: In WC_Product_Variable::get_variation_prices().
// $this->data_store is an instance of WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT
$prices = $this->data_store->read_price_data( $this, $for_display ); // array

// Case 2: In WC_Product_Variable_CanopyTour::get_variation_prices().
// $this->data_store is an instance of WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT
$prices = $this->data_store->read_price_data( $this, $for_display ); // null
```

But since the `read_price_data()` method is expected to return an `array` and yet it doesn't (or that it returns `null`), that's why PHP throws the "*Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...*" warning:

```
// The following code throws a warning.
foreach ( null as $key => $value ) {
    ...
}
```

### The Solution

You need to **use the proper data store *class*** for your custom (variable) product type.

I.e. Add an item to the [`WC_Data_Store::$stores`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Data_Store.html#21-51) `array`, where the key is the (variable) product type prefixed with `product-` (so in your case, it would be `product-variable_canopytour`), and the value is the `class` that handles the data store (e.g. `WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT` as in the below example).

You can do so via the [`woocommerce_data_stores`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Data_Store.html#75) filter, like so: (add to the active theme's `functions.php` file)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', function( $stores ){
    $stores['product-variable_canopytour'] = 'WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT';
    return $stores;
} );
```

### Additional Note

The constructor for `WC_Product_Variable_CanopyTour` should be defined the [same way](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#119-121) the parent `class` defines it, where the `$product` is optional and that it defaults to zero (`0`), like so:

```
class WC_Product_Variable_CanopyTour extends WC_Product_Variable {
    public function __construct( $product = 0 ) {
        $this->product_type = 'variable_canopytour';
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: PS: In the `functions.php` file, you got `add_action( 'admin_head', array($woo_ct, 'wcb_admin_head') );`, but I don't see a method named *wcb_admin_head* defined in the `WCB_Woocommerce_CanopyTour_Product_Type` class. Did you mean `add_action( 'admin_footer', array($woo_ct, 'wcb_admin_footer') );`?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! It was just this that needed me. I just need to know how to add the template to my custom product type. Now, about your comment of "admin_head", I was wrong to copy, what happens is that only pass the functions that made reference to the product type "variable_canopytour". I hope that has not been a problem, greetings!

Comment: You're welcome @JesúsMagallón. I updated the answer and hopefully it's more helpful. ;) Please let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Incredibly thoughtful and helpful answer. Thank you @SallyCJ ... At the risk of adding more pointless pedantic noise to the internet, couldn't you just set the product_type property directly in the class and get rid of the constructor altogether?
`public $product_type = 'variable_canopytour'`

Comment: Yes, indeed, @KerryRandolph. :) But you know, I was focused more on the `foreach` error back then and missed that part you've pointed. :p

Answer (score 0):

The error is originating from [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L83). What it simply tells you is that the `$prices` variable used in the `foreach` loop is not of a type that you can iterate over. The prices are fetched using

```
$prices = $this->data_store->read_price_data( $this, $for_display );
```

So whatever is returned from that `read_price_data` call is not what the rest of the codes expect it to be. I'm not sure exactly how this system operates and what is needed when you extend `WC_Product_Variable` etc and I can't set up a system to debug it. But if you trace the call stack backward from this point backward you will likely find out why this unexpected data is returned from this function.

Gut feeling says it could be some important part you forgot to add when you extended the class or something similar.